# Why use a SqlTransaction object in ADO.NET C#?

Tags: sql-server, database, transactions, commit, rollback

I'm working on a WPF application in ADO.NET C#. I'm using a local database to do some test. My question is: Why should I use a Transaction before executing, for example, an UPDATE/INSERT command?

I've tried to do `UPDATE` and `INSERT` commands with `SqlConnection`, `SqlCommand`, `SqlDataAdapter` and they work well, even if I've never used a `SqlTransaction` object on the `Connection` object. If I do (on a *Save Button*):

```
try
{
conn.Open();

SqlTransaction sqlTran = conn.BeginTransaction(IsolationLevel.Serializable);
dAdapter.SelectCommand.Transaction = sqlTran;
dAdapter.Update(dtTable);
sqlTran.Commit();
conn.Close();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
sqlTran.RollBack();
conn.Close();
}
```

what are the differences with the same instructions but without the transactions (and Commit/Rollback)?

Comment: First of all, you can't start a transaction before you have opened up the connection. Second, the benefit is that if `dAdapter.Update(dtTable);` ends up issuing multiple statements to the database, either all succeed or none succeed. If you don't use a transaction, you risk multiple statements succeeding before one fails/not persisted, and only the failed one will be rolled back, the previously succeeded statements would still be persisted. Depending on your case, that might be bad.

Comment: For instance, a data table containig 3 updated rows and one new one would persist the 3 updates, and then might fail because there is a primary key violation. The first 3 updates would still be persisted in the database without a transaction. With a transaction, however, once the fourth statement, the insert, fails with a primary key violation, your rollback would roll out the first 3 updates as well. This is basic transaction handling.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen So, with a transation, if I have to update 3 records and just one of them fails (with a primary key violation), the rollback will come back the database to the previous state, cancelling *all* the 3 update, won't it?